# Issue a warning in case a struct with dynamic fields contains a NaN value

Tags: matlab, dynamic, struct, warnings, nan

I have a struct containing a parameter set of measurement data. Sometimes the dataset is not complete and some parameters, which are missing, will be set to `NaN`.

Now I want to display a warning, if there is at least one (or more) `NaN` anywhere in the parameter set.

For example:

```
Parameter.mass=1;
Parameter.volume=2;
Parameter.force=NaN;
```

The problem is, that not every parameter set has the same fields.

So I am looking for something like:

```
if isnan(Parameter.*) >= 1
  display('Warning! Parameter set not complete!')
end
```

As i overlooked, that my struct has also another struct in it...

So there is also

```
Parameter.Info.Valve
Parameter.Info.Armature
```

Which causes a Error by using 'il_raffa' code [...]

```
if(isnan(Struct.(st_fields{i})))
```

Comment: Would it contain a `double` `NaN` or a `char` `'NaN'`? I just want to make sure that this is not a typo...

Comment: Sorry! my fault! double Nan not a char 'NaN'

Answer (score 3):

You can get the fields of a struct ([`fieldnames`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html)), then iterate over them. This can also be called recursively, in case you have nested structs, as shown in the example below:

```
function checkNaNFields(testedStruct, containerName)
if nargin < 2
  containerName = {inputname(1)};
end
fn = fieldnames(testedStruct);
for indFN = 1:numel(fn)
  field = testedStruct.(fn{indFN});
  if isstruct(field)
    % If the field is a struct, call recursively:
    checkNaNFields( field, [containerName, fn{indFN}] );
  elseif isnumeric(field) && isnan(field)
    warning(['Field "' strjoin([containerName, fn{indFN}],'.') '" contains a NaN value!']);  
  end
end
```

```
>> Parameter = struct('mass', 1, 'volume', 2, 'force', NaN, 'info', struct('value', NaN) );
>> checkNaNFields(Parameter);

Warning: Field "Parameter.force" contains a NaN value! 
> In checkNaNFields (line 12) 
Warning: Field "Parameter.info.value" contains a NaN value! 
> In checkNaNFields (line 12)
  In checkNaNFields (line 10)
```

---

I would also like to suggest a completely different approach - [objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example-representing-structured-data.html)! If you define a class with certain fields, you can set their [default values and validation functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/validate-property-values.html). If you're not familiar with the topic of Object-oriented programming (OOP), you can start by reading [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html).

Answer (score 3):

1) Assuming **struct fields contain values as `double`, `chararray`, `cellarray`, or nested `struct`** the following recursive function returns logical `true` if a `NaN` is found either as a `double` or as a string `'NaN'`:

```
function hasNaN = STRUCT_hasNaN(s)
    if(iscell(s)), c = s; else, c = struct2cell(s); end
    i = cellfun(@isnumeric, c);
    j = cellfun(@ischar, c);
    k = cellfun(@isstruct, c) | cellfun(@iscell, c);
    hasNaN = nnz(cellfun(@isnan, c(i))) || nnz(strcmpi(c(j), 'nan')) || nnz(cellfun(@STRUCT_hasNaN, c(k)));
end
```

which can be used as:

```
if(STRUCT_hasNaN(Parameter))
    disp('Warning! Parameter set not complete!');
end
```

2) Assuming **all fields contain values as double**, and the warning should be issued by at least a NaN value:

```
if(nnz(isnan(struct2array(Parameter))))
    disp('Warning! Parameter set not complete!');
end
```

3) Assuming the warning should be issued by the **value 'NaN' as a string**, as initially stated in the question:

```
if(nnz(strcmp(struct2cell(Parameter), 'NaN')))
    disp('Warning! Parameter set not complete!');
end
```

Comment: You get my vote as this is the closest to what the OP wanted. Although `struct2array` might be problematic if the struct can contain anything other than numbers (e.g. another `struct`)...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function `fieldnames` to get the names of the fields of a struct.

Once you'v got the list of the fields, you can scan them and check their values

You can set a counter and if it is greater than 0, ypu know at least a field is unvalid.

You can also save the index of the field foud not valid and list the nams of such fields.

```
Parameter.mass=1;
Parameter.volume=2;
Parameter.force=NaN

st_fields=fieldnames(Parameter)

cnt=0
for i=1:length(st_fields)
   if(strcmp(Parameter.(st_fields{i}),'NaN'))
      cnt=cnt+1
      idx(cnt)=i
   elseif(isnan(Parameter.(st_fields{i})))
      cnt=cnt+1
      idx(cnt)=i
   end
end
if(cnt > 0)
   disp('Warning! Parameter set not complete!')
   disp('The following Fields are unvalid:')
   for i=1:cnt
      st_fields{idx(i)}
   end
end
```

Comment: Ahh ... I overlooked, that my struct has also another struct in it. So there is a Parameter.Info.Valve and Parameter.Info.Armature